# Looping a Route in MapKit

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

I am currently learning Swift (in Xcode) and I'm trying to make an app. I have been following a tutorial to make a route in Mapkit.

Currently, I have it so that a user can type in a location and it creates a route to that location. Is there any way that I could make it so that it creates a loop?

Basically what would happen is that it would map a route to the location (e.g. an address, Starbucks, etc.) and then turn around and continue the route back to the starting point (but not just cross back the same way, it would cover different streets).

Hopefully that makes sense, here is my code:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  NavNinja
//
//  Created by Dakota on 2/11/24.
//


import SwiftUI
import MapKit


struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var cameraPosition: MapCameraPosition = .region(.userRegion)
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @State private var results = [MKMapItem]()
    @State private var mapSelection: MKMapItem?
    @State private var showDetails = false
    @State private var getDirections = false
    
    //ROUTE
    @State private var routeDisplaying = false
    @State private var route: MKRoute?
    @State private var routeDestination: MKMapItem?
    @State private var routeDistanceInMiles: Double = 0.0
    //ROUTE
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(position: $cameraPosition, selection: $mapSelection) {
            
            UserAnnotation()
            Annotation("My location", coordinate: .userLocation) {
                ZStack {
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                        .foregroundStyle(.blue.opacity(0.25))
                    
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: 12, height: 12)
                        .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                }
            }
            
            ForEach(results, id: \.self) { item in
                if routeDisplaying {
                    if item == routeDestination {
                        let placemark = item.placemark
                        Marker(placemark.name ?? "", coordinate: placemark.coordinate)
                    }
                } else {
                    let placemark = item.placemark
                    Marker(placemark.name ?? "", coordinate: placemark.coordinate)
                }
            }
            
            //ROUTE
            if let route {
                MapPolyline(route.polyline)
                    .stroke(.blue, lineWidth: 6)
            }
            //ROUTE
        }
        .overlay(alignment: .top) {
            TextField("Search for a location...", text: $searchText)
                .font(.subheadline)
                .padding(22)
                .background(.white)
                .padding()
                .shadow(radius: 10)
        }
        
        // Add route distance display
                    .overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                        if route != nil {
                            Text(String(format: "Route Distance: %.2f miles", routeDistanceInMiles))
                                .font(.footnote)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .padding(8)
                                .background(Color.black.opacity(0.7))
                                .cornerRadius(8)
                                .padding(10)
                        }
                    }
        
        .onSubmit(of: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.text/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
            Task { await searchPlaces() }
        }
        //ROUTE
        .onChange(of: getDirections, { oddValue, newValue in
            if newValue {
                fetchRoute()
            }
        })
        //ROUTE
        .onChange(of: mapSelection, { addValue, newValue in
            showDetails = newValue != nil
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $showDetails, content: {
            LocationDetailsView(mapSelection: $mapSelection,
                                show: $showDetails,
                                getDirections: $getDirections)
                .presentationDetents([.height(340)])
                .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled(upThrough: .height(340)))
                .presentationCornerRadius(12)
        })
        .mapControls {
            MapCompass()
            MapPitchToggle()
            MapUserLocationButton()
        }
    }
}
extension ContentView {
    func searchPlaces() async {
        let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchText
        request.region = .userRegion
        let results = try? await MKLocalSearch(request: request).start()
        self.results = results?.mapItems ?? []
    }
    
    //ROUTE
    func fetchRoute() {
        if let mapSelection {
            let request = MKDirections.Request()
            request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: .init(coordinate: .userLocation))
            request.destination    = mapSelection
            
            Task {
                let result = try? await MKDirections(request: request).calculate()
                route = result?.routes.first
                routeDestination = mapSelection
                
                withAnimation(.snappy) {
                    routeDisplaying = true
                    showDetails = false
                    
                    if let rect = route?.polyline.boundingMapRect, routeDisplaying {
                        cameraPosition = .rect(rect)
                    }
                    
                    // Calculate the total distance of the route in miles
                    if let totalDistanceInMeters = route?.distance {
                        // Convert meters to miles
                        let totalDistanceInMiles = totalDistanceInMeters / 1609.34 // 1 mile = 1609.34 meters
                        routeDistanceInMiles = totalDistanceInMiles
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //ROUTE
}
extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    static var userLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return .init(latitude: 25.7602, longitude: -80.1959)
    }
}
extension MKCoordinateRegion {
    static var userRegion: MKCoordinateRegion {
        return .init(center: .userLocation,
        latitudinalMeters: 1000,
        longitudinalMeters: 1000)
    }
}
#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

All code between two "//ROUTE" comments indicates that the cod ehas to do with mapping the route.

Comment: Where do data for the return route implied by "but not just cross back the same way, it would cover different streets" come from in your expected loop?

Comment: @ElTomato I'm not totally sure, I'm honestly pretty clueless here

Answer (score 0):

add steps to your route to force a loop using a different direction  using [MKRoute.Step](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkroute/step)
Each MKRoute.Step object corresponds to a single instruction that the person needs to follow when navigating between two points. For example, a step might involve following a single road until continuing along the route requires a turn.